# What does .between? method means in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a exercise of the school and i can't resolve it. Can you help me?
The problem is this:

> Try using a method that takes two arguments - use the between? method
>   to determine if the number 2 lies between the numbers 1 and 3.

I tried to find what is the *.between?* method but í couldn't find it.
I just know that is a method

Answer (score 20):

The method is [Comparable#between?](https://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F), and you can use it like this:

```
2.between?(1, 3)
# => true
```

Comment: 2.between?(3, 1)
=> false
how about this?

Comment: As the documentation states, the first parameter is a minimum value and the second parameter is a maximum.  It would be trivial to write a wrapper that doesn't care about order if you need one...

Answer (score 9):

use `between?` is the easiest way, I found most answers here didn't mention (ruby doc explanation is hard to understand too), using `between?` does INCLUDE the `min` and `max` value.

for example:

```
irb(main):001:0> 2.between?(1, 3)
=> true
irb(main):002:0> 3.between?(1, 3)
=> true
irb(main):003:0> 1.between?(1, 3)
=> true
irb(main):004:0> 0.between?(1, 3)
=> false
```

by the way, ruby doc quote (too hard to understand for newbie):

> between?(min, max) → true or false Returns false if obj <=> min is
>   less than zero or if anObject <=> max is greater than zero, true
>   otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

From "[between](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F)" ruby documentation:

> between?(min, max) → true or false
>   Returns false if obj <=> min is less than zero or if anObject <=> max is greater than zero, true otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Uh oh, and of course, it's `#===` method for ranges:

```
( 1..3 ) === 2 #=> true
( 1..3 ) === 4 #=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Range#cover?` as a solution :

```
(1..3).cover? 2 #=> true
```